# Imported function is undefined when used in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, strapi

I have a js file like this:

```
const {foo} = require('some-lib')

console.log(foo === undefined)  // for testing only

module.exports = {
    async bar() {
        let baz = foo();
    }
}
```

This gets me `error TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined`, even though the console.log prints false. What is happening on here?

(The actual code is roughly the second example [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/parameters.html#extracting-requests-filters), I'm trying to use the `buildQuery` function.)

EDIT:
Per request, here is a minimal reproducible example:

1. Install Strapi with the [quickstart](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-and-create-a-new-project) setup (`yarn create strapi-app my-project --quickstart`)
2. With Strapi running, go to `localhost:1337/admin`, click `Content Type Builder` in the sidebar and create a minimal `article` content type. It only needs the title "article", no other attributes.
3. In `Roles & Permissions`, go to `public` and select all, then save.
4. Now modify `my-project/api/article/services/article.js` to look like this:

```
'use strict';

const {buildQuery} = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  find() {buildQuery({model: 'article'})}
};
```

This gives the error described above when calling `localhost:1337/article`. Note that the example is taken almost verbatim from Strapi's [documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/parameters.html#concept), and note also that `console.log(buildQuery === undefined)` directly after the import prints false.

EDIT2:

It seems that this is actually a bug in Strapi, I've opened an issue on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5306

Comment: `some-lib` doesn't expose anything
you can checkit looking the code in `node_modules/some-lib` folder

Comment: `some-lib` doesn't have a named export called `foo`. Don't try to abstract the code so much it becomes useless-the answer to the question as asked is obvious.

Comment: the error is coming from `const {foo} = require('some-lib')` line.

Comment: how do you use this module? you export `bar()` function.. not `foo`

Comment: I'm trying to export the `bar` function, and `some-lib` is present in node_modules and does export `foo` (other imports from it work fine).

Comment: I'm afraid it will be difficult to help your further without a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: @iulo I've added one.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind require() is returning a promise ,

```
const {foo} = require('some-lib')

module.exports = {
bar : async  ()=>{
let baz = foo();
return baz;
                }
            }
```

should this return bar as a module contains foo

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think I'm doing it in exactly this way, am I not?

Comment: in your example you are doing this '
module.exports = {
    async bar() {
        let baz = foo();
    }
}' it should return {bar:undefined} i think because bar() is void not returning anything

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

```
const { foo } = require("some-lib");

console.log(foo === undefined); // for testing only

exports.foo = async () => {
  let baz = foo();
  return baz;
  //or just return foo();
};
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. It looks like you are suggesting reading a different property from `some-lib`. What makes you think that the different property exists?

Comment: it was a mistake it should be const {foo} = require('some-lib')
 same as the example in addition to that the export like this should be working otherwise there will be an issue with ''some-lib'' itself